# In NoSQL system, example Each Lesson has many Exercise, do we need to check the exist of Lesson twice before inserting exercise?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

Ok, LessonNo is ID of Lesson table & LessonNo is foreign key of Exercise. Each Lesson has many Exercise but each Exercise only belongs to 1 Lesson.

Here is the gui

```
Text Box "Lesson No":....

Text Area "Exercise":......

Button "Insert Exercise":
```

When user click "**Insert Exercise**", the system will check if Lesson exists. If it does then they will call `insertExercise (String exercise)` method

```
public boolean checkIfThisLessonNoExists(int lessonNo){
    //query from datastore
    return true or false;
}
if(checkIfThisLessonNoExists(lessonNo)){
     insertExercise (exercise);
}
public boolean insertExercise (String exercise){
    Transaction tx=datastore.beginTransaction();
    try{
       Entity e=new Entity("Exercise");
       e.setProperty("exercise",exercise);
       datastore.put(e);
       tx.commit();
    }
    catch{
    }
}
```

If we do like the above, then will we have any problem?

In Google App Engine or any NoSQL system, there is no Foreign Constraint. So, what if at the time we are doing the insert the lesson got deleted???

To solve that problen. DO we need to check the `lessonNo` again inside the `Transaction`?

So, should we do like the following?:

```
  public boolean insertExercise (int lessonNo, String exercise){
        Transaction tx=datastore.beginTransaction();
        try{
           if(checkIfThisLessonNoExists(lessonNo)){
             Entity e=new Entity("Exercise");
             e.setProperty("exercise",exercise);
             datastore.put(e);
             tx.commit();
           }
           else{
                tx.rollback();
           }
        }
        catch{
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system you've described cannot prevent the insertion of an invalid `Exercise` - the `Lesson` can be deleted or otherwise invalidated at any time, so even if you add a `checkIfThisLessonNoExists(lessonNo)` check inside of `insertExercise` all this will do is reduce the likelihood of inserting an invalid `Exercise` without eliminating this possibility.

The simplest solution is to accept that your datastore is not going to be 100% consistent and to take corrective measures when querying it, namely when querying the set of `Exercises` you should filter out any `Exercise` that is associated with a non-existent `Lesson` and make the user aware that the list of `Exercises` you've returned is only valid for that timestamp and cannot reflect any changes to the `Lessons` or `Exercises` effected at a later timestamp.  (I do not recommend that you delete invalid `Exercises` when performing this query as this will potentially transform a readonly query into a readwrite query - instead, schedule a cleanup process to periodically delete invalid data from the store.)

Comment: If Exercise is a child of Lesson (Ex: **Entity lesson1 = new Entity("Lesson", "Lesson1"); Key lesson1Key=lesson1.getKey();  Entity exercise1 =new Entity("Exercise", "exercise1", lessonKey1)**.  If that is the case & if we delete the Lesson, will it delete the exercises accordingly?

Comment: @Tom No, a parent entity does not need to exist, so if you delete a parent then its children will not be deleted and will continue to reference the non-existent parent